# bash - pulling content from array via index

Tags: arrays, bash

I am having trouble with a script that prints out the index and items of the array and then allows the user to input an index that will print out that specific item of the array.

```
array=(abc def ghi)

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#array[*]} ]; do
    echo "[$i] ${array[$i]}"
    i=$(($i+1));
done

echo -e "select an index: "; read answer

#this is the part that is troubling me

for index in ${!array[*]}; do
    if [[ $answer == $index ]]; then
        echo ${array[$index]}
        break
    else
        echo "invalid"
        break
    fi
done
```

so if the user enters 0, it should print abc. 1 would be def etc. It currently only works for index 0.

Comment: What you're looking for is `echo "${array[answer]}"`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: added the missing quote... had to retype it because the script is on another device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of problems in there that I can find:

1. you need a space right after $item to separate from the ]
2. $item should probably be $index
3. most importantly, remove the break after the "echo invalid" which is the reason the loop exits right after testing against '0' and doesn't check for the next array indexes. Using a flag then you should control if the answer matched any of the valid indexes, otherwise print the "invalid" message. I used a very explicit string test there for clarity.

A running code should look like:

```
array=(abc def ghi)
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#array[*]} ]; do
    echo "[$i] ${array[$i]}"
    i=$(($i+1));
done
echo -e "select an index: "; read answer

for index in ${!array[*]}; do
    found="FALSE"
    if [[ "$answer" == "$index" ]]; then
        found="TRUE"
        echo "${array[$index]}"
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$found" == "FALSE" ]; then
   echo "Invalid input $answer"
fi
```

Comment: apologies for the poor syntax... but this seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. I think the real problem in the logic was the break at the `else` branch, because that would basically not proceed to test index values other than the first, 0 in this case.